# XCode/Flutter: How do I fix "ExportOptions.plist" is invalid error when trying to export my app?

Tags: flutter, xcode, plist

My app is written in Flutter, and I have been Ad Hoc distributing it to my Iphone multiple times now for sake of testing. To do this, I open my Flutter project in Xcode, Archive it, select distribute, then export, then install. This has successfully worked at least 20 times, as I have been doing a lot of testing. Like normal, I made some changes to my code - I was fixing the UI graph output - and went to distribute to my phone as usual when I got the error "ExportOptions.plist" is invalid.

After some googling, I ran updates on flutter dependencies and deleted the ios folder and generated a new one. The code still runs on a simulated Iphone no problem. It will also run on my Iphone while plugged in to my mac. However, I need it to run while not plugged in, hence the Ad Hoc distribution. I have seen people give examples of their exportOptions.plist, but I don't even know where to find it. I can't seem to access it in Flutter and I don't know where to locate it in Xcode.

Where specifically is ExportOptions.plist and how do I make mine "valid" again?

Update: I have located ExportOptions.plist. I will provide a screenshot. However, I am not sure what about it is causing the file to be invalid. How do I make the exportOptions valid again? [image: screenshot of exportOptions]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this and wanted to post in case any one else got stuck on this too. It was actually an extremely simple fix. If your exportOptions.plist file name is invalid check the complete directory path you are saving it to. After you have seen where it is trying to save, create a new location/folder, with an entirely different pathway, and save it to the new location. This did the trick for me.